# Create Oracle Table based in XML file

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm trying to create a oracle table separated with columns, with a xml file.
I used the sql command to create the table:

```
create table  mytable of XMLType;

insert into mytable2 values(XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR','XMLFileName.xml'),nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
```

The file is inserted into the table with a xml structure, but I need to view in columns or selecting only the field into the tag  after the token ct:iid.
For example, in the first tag  I need to select the value "OrphanedBSCs".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<ArrayOfRootEntityType xmlns:umts="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/UMTS/2010/07" xmlns:tra70="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Connect/2010/08" xmlns:ct="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/CommonTypes/2009/05" xmlns:co="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Common/2009/07" xmlns:gsm80="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/GSM/2011/04" xmlns:ecs="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/EWS/ECSCoverageTypes/2011/08" xmlns:gsm70="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/GSM/2010/08" xmlns:config="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Configuration/2010/08" xmlns:cdma="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/CDMA/2010/12" xmlns:co70="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Common/2010/08" xmlns:umts80="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/UMTS/2011/04" xmlns:eqp70="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Equipment/2010/08" xmlns:co80="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Common/2011/04" xmlns:util="http://www.aircominternational.com/contract/Util/2009/10" xmlns:tra80="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Connect/2011/04" xmlns:umts70="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/UMTS/2010/08" xmlns:eqp80="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Equipment/2011/04" xmlns:tra="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Connect/2009/09" xmlns:lte="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/LTE/2010/08" xmlns:eds="http://www.aircominternational.com/contract/EDS/2009/05" xmlns:umts2="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/UMTS/2009/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:eqp="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/Equipment/2009/09" xmlns:gsm="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/GSM/2009/09" xmlns:lte80="http://www.aircominternational.com/Schemas/LTE/2011/04">
  <RootEntityType xsi:type="gsm:MSCType" ct:iid="OrphanedBSCs" ct:bvid="IVLP_201303" ct:eid="223127">
    <Security>
      <CreateDate>2013-03-21T10:01:18</CreateDate>
      <ModifyDate>2013-03-21T10:01:19</ModifyDate>
      <CreateUser>EDS_SOA_Client</CreateUser>
      <ModifyUser>EDS_SOA_Client</ModifyUser>
      <UserGroup>All</UserGroup>
      <Permissions>
        <Owner>write</Owner>
        <Group>write</Group>
        <All>read</All>
      </Permissions>
    </Security>
    <CustomFields>
      <Field Group="SOURCE" Value="NETWORK"/>
      <Field Group="LastUpdated" Value="3/21/2013 10:01:18 AM"/>
    </CustomFields>
    <Location ct:iid="OrphanedBSCs_msc_loc" ct:eid="119692"/>
    <gsm:BSCs>
      <gsm:BSC ct:iid="OrphanedSites" ct:bvid="IVLP_201303" ct:eid="223128">
        <Security>
          <CreateDate>2013-03-21T10:01:19</CreateDate>
          <ModifyDate>2013-03-21T10:01:19</ModifyDate>
          <CreateUser>EDS_SOA_Client</CreateUser>
          <ModifyUser>EDS_SOA_Client</ModifyUser>
          <UserGroup>All</UserGroup>
          <Permissions>
            <Owner>write</Owner>
            <Group>write</Group>
            <All>read</All>
          </Permissions>
        </Security>
        <CustomFields>
          <Field Group="SOURCE" Value="NETWORK"/>
          <Field Group="LastUpdated" Value="3/21/2013 10:01:19 AM"/>
        </CustomFields>
        <Location ct:iid="OrphanedSites_bsc_loc" ct:eid="119693"/>
        <gsm:Parent ct:iid="OrphanedBSCs" ct:eid="223127"/>
        <gsm:BSCId>0</gsm:BSCId>
        <gsm:AllowedOperations>ReadWrite</gsm:AllowedOperations>
      </gsm:BSC>
    </gsm:BSCs>
    <gsm:AllowedOperations>ReadWrite</gsm:AllowedOperations>
  </RootEntityType>
  <RootEntityType xsi:type="gsm:MSCType" ct:iid="HUAWEI_2G_MSC" ct:bvid="IVLP_201303" ct:eid="223131">
    <Security>
      <CreateDate>2013-03-21T10:01:21</CreateDate>
      <ModifyDate>2013-03-21T10:01:21</ModifyDate>
      <CreateUser>EDS_SOA_Client</CreateUser>
      <ModifyUser>EDS_SOA_Client</ModifyUser>
      <UserGroup>All</UserGroup>
      <Permissions>
        <Owner>write</Owner>
        <Group>write</Group>
        <All>read</All>
      </Permissions>
    </Security>
    <CustomFields>
      <Field Group="SOURCE" Value="NETWORK"/>
      <Field Group="LastUpdated" Value="3/21/2013 10:01:21 AM"/>
    </CustomFields>
    <Location ct:iid="HUAWEI_2G_MSC_msc_loc" ct:eid="119696"/>
    <gsm:BSCs>
      <gsm:BSC ct:iid="BSCMG35" ct:bvid="IVLP_201303" ct:eid="223252">
        <Security>
          <CreateDate>2013-03-21T10:01:30</CreateDate>
          <ModifyDate>2013-03-21T10:01:30</ModifyDate>
          <CreateUser>EDS_SOA_Client</CreateUser>
          <ModifyUser>EDS_SOA_Client</ModifyUser>
          <UserGroup>All</UserGroup>
          <Permissions>
            <Owner>write</Owner>
            <Group>write</Group>
            <All>read</All>
          </Permissions>
        </Security>
        <CustomFields>
          <Field Group="SOURCE" Value="NETWORK"/>
          <Field Group="LastUpdated" Value="3/21/2013 10:01:22 AM"/>
        </CustomFields>
        <Location ct:iid="BSCMG35_bsc_loc" ct:eid="119817"/>
        <gsm:Parent ct:iid="HUAWEI_2G_MSC" ct:eid="223131"/>
        <gsm:BSCId>0</gsm:BSCId>
        <gsm:AllowedOperations>ReadWrite</gsm:AllowedOperations>
      </gsm:BSC>
      <gsm:BSC ct:iid="BSCMG34" ct:bvid="IVLP_201303" ct:eid="223270">
        <Security>
          <CreateDate>2013-03-21T10:01:30</CreateDate>
          <ModifyDate>2013-03-21T10:01:30</ModifyDate>
          <CreateUser>EDS_SOA_Client</CreateUser>
          <ModifyUser>EDS_SOA_Client</ModifyUser>
          <UserGroup>All</UserGroup>
          <Permissions>
            <Owner>write</Owner>
            <Group>write</Group>
            <All>read</All>
          </Permissions>
        </Security>
        <CustomFields>
          <Field Group="SOURCE" Value="NETWORK"/>
          <Field Group="LastUpdated" Value="3/21/2013 10:01:22 AM"/>
        </CustomFields>
        <Location ct:iid="BSCMG34_bsc_loc" ct:eid="119835"/>
        <gsm:Parent ct:iid="HUAWEI_2G_MSC" ct:eid="223131"/>
        <gsm:BSCId>0</gsm:BSCId>
        <gsm:AllowedOperations>ReadWrite</gsm:AllowedOperations>
      </gsm:BSC>
    </gsm:BSCs>
    <gsm:AllowedOperations>ReadWrite</gsm:AllowedOperations>
  </RootEntityType>
</ArrayOfRootEntityType>
```

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this.  You could create a view on the XML data, or create a table w/the columns you need and do a insert/select with only the elements needed.  I would urge you to read the Oracle Docs, as they are pretty good - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/toc.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
select *
from   table-with-xml-column t
,      xmltable
       ( 'PATH/TO/WHAT/YOU/NEED' 
         passing t.xml_column_name
         columns column1 number       path 'path1'
         columns column2 char(1 byte) path 'path2'
         columns column3 varchar2(30) path 'path3'
       ) t2
```

Tip! Please take note that handling XML columns can be painfully slow, Oracle seems to parse the contents of xmltype often. Do not introduce complex joins across XML and relation data or high frequently executed statements without testing performance with realistic size of XML contents.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help, this exemplo is very userful, but in some tags I can not use it. For example, in this tag "<gsm:BSCs>
      <gsm:BSC ct:iid="BSCMG35" ct:bvid="IVLP_201303" ct:eid="223252">" I can not get the value "BSCMG35" the message error ORA-19228:XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix 'gsm' local-name 'gsm:BSCs' was displayed.
I using the query:
SELECT  ab.*
FROM MSC_XML p,
XMLTable('/ArrayOfRootEntityType/RootEntityType/gsm:BSCs/gsm:BSC' PASSING p.OBJECT_VALUE
COLUMNS
MSC VARCHAR2(38) PATH '@*:iid') ab;

Comment: ah ok. Please remember to check namespace usage. Without it, either an error or no access :-). For instance like this: select extractValue(l_xml, '/ipinfo/ip_address', g_ns)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help.
I solved my problem setting the namespaces used in the xml file.
This is the new query to select any data in xml:

select *
from   table-with-xml-column t
,      xmltable
       ( 
        (XMLNAMESPACES('url_indicated_in_xmlfile_about_ct' as "ct"),
       'PATH/TO/WHAT/YOU/NEED' 
         passing t.xml_column_name
         columns column1 number       path 'path1'
         columns column2 char(1 byte) path 'path2'
         columns column3 varchar2(30) path 'path3'
       ) t2

Comment: Ok, great to hear that you have been helped. I think a good place for this addition is to put it in the question itself using 'edit'. The reviewers might move it there.